# R cbinding lists of data.tables

Tags: r, data.table

I have two lists of data.tables of equal length in R. I want to element-wise cbind them. I sort of want to do a zip function where the input is two lists and the output is one list as illustrated below:

```
list1 list2                  list3
----- -----       ----------------
 dt1a  dt2a       cbind(dt1a,dt2a)
 dt1b  dt2b  =>   cbind(dt1b,dt2b)
 dt1c  dt2c       cbind(dt1c,dt2c)
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: `dput` your list1 and list2

Comment: Something like this `lapply(seq_along(list1), function(i) cbind(list1[[i]], list2[[i]]))`

Comment: @suchait I just looked up `dput`, and I don't get it. It just writes an object to a file.

Answer (score 2):

```
list3 <- mapply(cbind, list1, list2, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```